# Using pipelight on fedora?

Tags: fedora, firefox

I am trying to get the silverlight plugin to work in firefox so I can watch netflix. I did some research and figured out I needed to install pipelight, so I got that. The same information said to use the command:

```
pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

but when I did that, it says the command does not exist. I've confirmed that the package is installed correctly, so I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: which command doesn't exist? the `pipelight-plugin` command? What's the package that provides it? Try running it with the full (absolute) path then.  Otherwise, check with `type pipelight-plugin` or `rpmquery -l PKGNAME` to look for the program location.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need pipelight anymore, in fact  [last week Neflix announced official support from Linux using HTML5](http://techblog.netflix.com/2017/03/update-on-html5-video-for-netflix.html).

You can view either using Chrome or Firefox.

In Fedora 25 using Firefox 52, you don't need anything only to enable DRM:

Go to URL `about:preferences#content`

Comment: When I try it just takes me to this page: https://help.netflix.com/en/node/23742